# Confused on how Swift nested functions work

Tags: function, oop, swift

For example, take this code:

```
func jediTrainer () -> ((String, Int) -> String) {
  func train(name: String, times: Int) -> (String) {
    return "\(name) has been trained in the Force \(times) times"
  }
  return train
}
let train = jediTrainer()
train("Obi Wan", 3)
```

I am completely confused as to what is going on in this function. jediTrainer takes no parameters, and returns a function called train. When we say "train = jediTrainer()" are we now storing the FUNCTION "train" into the variable called "train", as it returned that function that's now stored in the variable? Can you please break down what exactly is going on here into steps? Thank you so much!

Comment: What is making you confused is that you have given your new function the same name. jediTrainer takes no parameters but it returns a function that does accept two parameters. You have created a new function named train which behaves exactly as it should.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So then the VARIABLE train is storing the FUNCTION train which you can then call?

Comment: The var can be anything including a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift functions are first class objects that means functions can be referenced by variables, passed as parameters and returned from other functions.

In your case jediTrainer() returns a function which is a nested function in itself. So let train is referring to train() function in jediTrainer. Now you could call that train function using train variable.

For more information on this please refer to Function Types and related topics [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You also have an opinion of definining functions inside a bodies of other functions.These are called nested function .
By default Nested functions is hidden from outside world .It can still be called and used by its enclosing function .An enclosing function can also  return one of nested functions ,thus allowing the nested function to be used in another scope .

```
func  aFunc (flag:Book)->(Int)->Int
{

func plus ( input:Int )->Int 
{
return input + 1
}

func minus ( input:Int )->Int 
{
return input - 1
}

if (flag)
{
return plus
}

else
{
return minus 
}
}
```